# MSDeploy IIS7 Sync Web Servers

Tags: iis-7, msdeploy

I am using the following MSDeploy command to pull content and settings from a production server to a staging server nightly.

msdeploy -verb:sync -source:webServer,wmsvc=xx.xx.xx.xx,username=xxxxx,password=xxxxxx,authType=basic -allowUntrusted=true -dest:webServer

As documented [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569021%28WS.10%29.aspx) the "webServer" provider uses several other providers.  Is there any way to exclude the "machineConfig32" and "machineConfig64" linked providers from being executed?

Thanks.

Updated:
Using a manifest works:

```
<sitemanifest>
   <appHostConfig path="siteNameHere" />
   <appHostSchema />
   <contentPath path="siteNameHere" />
   <rootWebConfig32 />
   <rootWebConfig64 />
</sitemanifest>
```

with MSDeploy command:
msdeploy" -verb:sync -source:manifest=d:\msdeploy\deploymanifest.xml,wmsvc=xx.xx.xx.xx,username=xxxxxx,password=xxxxxx,authType=basic -allowUntrusted=true -dest:manifest=d:\msdeploy\deploymanifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked extensions you can exclude are covered [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28WS.10%29.aspx) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569028%28WS.10%29.aspx):

I don't see yours listed there, but it may be worth a try. Sometimes this doco is out of date.

That said, you may want to try to "build up" less inclusive providers using manifests rather than "tearing down" an all-inclusive one. Try the following [link](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/423/using-custom-manifests/) for the info.. (package manifests)

Then you can have a package command like:  (my IIS6 standard package command, note this won't work exactly as it's IIS6, just serving up an example)

`-verb:sync -source:manifest=$manifestFile -dest:package=$appName.zip,encryptPassword=MyPassword -enableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -declareParamFile:$parametersFile"`

and deploy:

`-verb:sync -source:package=$appname.zip,encryptPassword=MyPassword -dest:auto -setParamFile=$appname_$computernamesetParameters.xml`

In the manifest I then have the site, the content directory, a registry location I need, and even com components and the like.

Comment: Thanks. Using a manifest works, but I am limited to a single site by specifying the site name (see updated question above).  I would like to replicate the entire web server except for the machine.config.

Comment: Understandable; did you -disableLink:machineConfig32 (&64) with your webserver provider argument? I wouldn't be surprised if it did work even though MSFT doesn't list it as a valid option. My apologies, I don't have my IIS7 lab up and running right now to give it a shot...

Answer (score 2):

You can just skip those objects from the sync operation all together by adding the following to your command line: `-skip:objectName=machineconfig32 -skip:objectName=machineConfig64`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - there is no direct way to exclude linked providers. However - you can sync individual providers by getting the dependency list.